# Powershell - copy files of under a particular size, while keeping directory structure

Tags: windows, powershell, file-transfer

I need to create a script that will copy files from multiple users PCs to a shared Server folder.
There are going to be restrictions on the types of files that can be copied, and indeed the size of the files.

I currently have this running;

```
$date = (Get-Date).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")

$DestPath =  "Z:\data\username\\$date"

mkdir $DestPath

$SourcePath = "C:\users\username\Documents\Foldername"

Copy-Item -Path $SourcePath  -Exclude *.exe, *.zip -destination $DestPath -Recurse
```

It creates the folders, based on today's date okay, copies all the files across with the exception of .exe and .zip files, but in some cases these are required - and as they are fairly small they are allowed. (Which means they get manually copied across)
What I do need to do is add to or change the above script that will allow all files of under a certain size which, in this case is under 100MB to be copied across, while maintaining the directory structure of the parent folder. Some users go 10 or so folders deep.

Multiple users use the script, so hard-coding directory names per user is done in the $SourcePath

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This PowerShell code should do it (untested) :

```
Get-ChildItem $SourcePath | where-object {$_.length -lt 2000000} | Copy-Item -Destination $DestPath
```

Comment: Thanks Harry, the Get-ChildItem only seems to work on the parent directory, without digging down to the other sub folders.
 I added "-Depth 10", and all that did was bring all the sub folders into the parent folder. I'll continue to work on it.

Comment: You need `-Recurse`.

Answer (score 1):

The following script is now working:

- Recursive, goes down at least 4 layers (Tested)
- Excludes the files as requested
- If Exclude is with Get-childItem, it will only function for the parent directory, but not any child directories

```
$DestPath =  "Z:\data\username\\$date"

mkdir $DestPath

$SourcePath = "C:\users\username\Documents\Foldername"

Get-ChildItem $SourcePath | where-object {$_.length -lt 200000000} | Copy-Item -Recurse -Exclude *.exe, *.zip, *.iso, *.rar, *.bak -Destination $DestPath
```